# Does the IsolatedStorage location change when assembly version changes?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, .net-assembly, isolatedstorage

I'm reading about Windows' [IsolatedStorage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) and I'm trying to understand what's appropriate to put in there.

There seems to be a few levels of "isolation", including variants for roaming users.  The ones I'm curious about are:

- `DomainIsolationByUser`

  Isolation by user, domain, and assembly. Each assembly has a separate substore within the domain.
- `AssemblyIsolationByUser`

  Isolation by user and assembly.

**Does "isolation by assembly" mean an assembly that's updated to a new version will not have access to the previous version's data?**

By "updated", I mean a new version in the manifest.  Say, updated by ClickOnce from `1_0_0_0` to `1_0_0_1`.